# How to test BGTaskScheduler in App (with out using debugger)

Tags: xcode, background-process, bgtaskscheduler

I have a `BGTaskScheduler` scheduled for background process. It is running in debugger mode but not working with out debugger. I have tried to test it on `TestFlight` as well, did not work.

I have tested it with the help of private function provider by Apple for debugging purpose.

```
e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"TASK_IDENTIFIER"]
```

([Click Here for details](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/starting_and_terminating_tasks_during_development))

It is working fine in debugger mode when we simulate the background process.
Now I want to test it normally using the application flow on `TestFlight`. But it is not calling `BGProcessingTaskRequest`. Any solution?

Comment: have you got any solution here? I am also facing similar issue.